# error: column "car_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some tables

```
all_cars(id, name, image, price)
cars_info(car_id, ps, engine, sit_place, fsk)
cars_details(car_id, info)
cars_price(car_id, time_zone, km, price)
```

I want to join all tables like this:

```
  const d = await pool.query(`
    SELECT 

    all_cars.id,
    all_cars.name,
    all_cars.image,
    all_cars.price,

    cars_info.car_id,
    cars_info.ps,
    cars_info.engine,
    cars_info.sit_place,
    cars_info.fsk,

    cars_details.car_id,
    cars_details.info,

    cars_price.car_id,
    cars_price.time_zone,
    cars_price.km,
    cars_price.price

    FROM all_cars

    INNER JOIN cars_info 
    ON all_cars.id = cars_info.car_id

    INNER JOIN cars_details 
    ON all_cars.id = cars_details.car_id

    INNER JOIN cars_price
    ON all_cars.id = cars_price.car_id

    GROUP BY all_cars.id
  `);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> error: column "car_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

And if I group by car_id then I got group ps, then I group by ps then I got the others.

If I dont group it I get 5x the same row. If not I got error.

Why I get this error? Is there a better way to do this and how can I solve this error above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clause `GROUP BY` doesn't make any sense if there's no [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) in your statement. You should rather use [`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-select-distinct/) for your purpose, assuming you have duplicate records with respect to "*if I dont group it I get 5x the same row*".

```
  const d = await pool.query(`
    SELECT DISTINCT

    all_cars.id,
    all_cars.name,
    all_cars.image,
    all_cars.price,

    cars_info.car_id,
    cars_info.ps,
    cars_info.engine,
    cars_info.sit_place,
    cars_info.fsk,

    cars_details.car_id,
    cars_details.info,

    cars_price.car_id,
    cars_price.time_zone,
    cars_price.km,
    cars_price.price

    FROM all_cars

    INNER JOIN cars_info 
    ON all_cars.id = cars_info.car_id

    INNER JOIN cars_details 
    ON all_cars.id = cars_details.car_id

    INNER JOIN cars_price
    ON all_cars.id = cars_price.car_id
  `);
```

Comment: thank you very much! Is this sql statement slow on rows where I have over hundred thousands items ? Or can it be better

Comment: There's not much that can be do here by changing the query. If you want to improve the efficiency, you can try using indices on the fields which you join on, namely "*all_cars.id*", "*cars_info.car_id*", "*cars_details.car_id*" and "*cars_price.car_id*".